# Copy and moving an entire sheet to another workbook. 1mil rows to 65536 rows

Tags: vba, excel, compatibility

The following is part of my code that involves copying an entire named sheet from one master file to a new unsaved file that's being worked on:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("VehicleList").Copy _
   After:=Workbooks(2).Sheets(1)
```

So this worked fine to place the sheet into workbook 2 but now the files we're dealing with are in old excel mode which is throwing up the following error due to old excel having less rows:

> "Excel cannot insert the sheets into the destination workbook, because it contains fewer rows and columns"

How can I tweak the copy and pasting into `Workbooks(2)` without breaking the code? I thought defining a range of 1000 rows to copy and move would work, but this also gave an error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where's your code for the 1000 rows bit?

Comment: I modified to; `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("VehicleList").Range(A1:F1000).Copy _
   After:=Workbooks(2).Sheets(1)`

Comment: and ... did it work?

Comment: @user3598756 I think that means it doesn't. That's what he tried and I asked him to put in.

Comment: Correct so that gave an 'expected variable or procedure' error. I'm wondering if there is simply a clean way to copy an entire sheet like I had but accounting for the difference in number of rows between excel versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want the values (i.e. I'm speeding it up by not doing a copy paste) you can do:

```
Workbooks(2).Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
Workbooks(2).Sheets(2).Range("A1:F1000").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("VehicleList").Range("A1:F1000").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim targetWs As Worksheet

    With Workbooks("MyWorkbookname").Sheets("VehicleList") '<--| fully qualify reference wanted worksheet in the wanted workbook
        Set targetWs = SetOrGetSheet(Workbooks(2), .name) '<--| get the (new) target worksheet on the target workbook named after referenced sheet
        Intersect(.Range("A1:F1000"), .UsedRange).Copy targetWs.Cells(1, 1) '<--| copy range to target worksheet on the target workbook
        If targetWs.name <> .name Then MsgBox "a new sheet has been created in " & targetWs.Parent.name & " with name " & targetWs.name
    End With
End Sub

Function SetOrGetSheet(targetWb As Workbook, shtName As String) As Worksheet
    targetWb.Worksheets.Add '<--| add a new sheet in the target workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set SetOrGetSheet = targetWb.Worksheets(shtName) '<--| try and get any possible target workbook sheet with the passed name
    If SetOrGetSheet Is Nothing Then targetWb.ActiveSheet.name = shtName '<--| if target workbook has no worksheet with passed name then name the new one after it
    Set SetOrGetSheet = targetWb.ActiveSheet 'return the new worksheet
End Function
```

should you be afraid your range-to-copy could exceed 65 rows and/or 256 columns than you should add its size check

---

**edit** for values pasting only

should you be interested in pasting values only then you can go like follows:

```
Sub main()
    SetOrGetSheet(Workbooks(2), "VehicleList").Range("A1:F1000").value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("VehicleList").Range("A1:F1000").value '<--| copy values form source to target worksheet
End Sub
```

while `SetOrGetSheet()` function stays the same as above

as you may have guessed that `function` is there for a more general approach where you may want (or just *have*) to handle the possibilty of *target* workbook having a worksheet named after *"VehicleList"* already

Comment: Useful thank you. I went with Tim's answer for pure simplicity of moving the values.

Comment: you are welcome. I edited my answer to both take into account the pure values pasting and 1) show you the mere implementation in your main code is quite short (1 line of code) 2) give you info to make your mind up about the use of `SetOrGetSheet()` function